# ClassNotFoundException by joram jar in grails

Tags: java, grails, jms

I have old JMS application (using JORAM), now I am trying to integrate it with Grails, my all JMS-related Java classes in src folder. I have put `joram and mom jar 3rd party jar` in `lib` folder, Whenever I am starting application then getting `ClassNotFoundException`, I have debugged the app and found in `joram jar`  where jar class is unable to load a class which is present in src, look like `classloader` issue, is any buddy have idea about `classloader` issue, can anyone please help here.
help will be appreciated.